# How to merge images as transparent layers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

I am working on video editor for raspberry pi, and I have a problem with speed of placing image over image. Currently, using imagemagick it takes up to 10 seconds just to place one image over another, using 1080x1920 png images, on raspberry pi, and that's way too much. With the number of images time goes up as well. Any ideas on how to speed it up?
Imagemagick code:

```
composite -blend 90 img1.png img2.png new.png
```

Video editor with yet slow opacity support [here](https://github.com/Bondpe/vira/)

--------EDIT--------

slightly faster way:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
size_X, size_Y = 1920, 1080#  put images resolution, else output may look wierd
image1 = np.resize(np.asarray(Image.open('img1.png').convert('RGB')), (size_X, size_Y, 3))
image2 = np.resize(np.asarray(Image.open('img2.png').convert('RGB')), (size_X, size_Y, 3))
output = image1*transparency+image2*(1-transparency)
Image.fromarray(np.uint8(output)).save('output.png')
```

Comment: Please specify the programming language you are using, and the relevant code you currently have.

Comment: Do not post your code as comment. Edit your question to add it in there. And add the 'python' tag.

Comment: It's no use saying it takes 10s if we cannot see the images and their sizes, nor know which version and which quantisation level of ImageMagick you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as another option, I tried in [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) (full disclosure: I'm the pyvips maintainer, so I'm not very neutral):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time
import pyvips

start = time.time()

a = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access="sequential")
b = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[2], access="sequential")
out = a * 0.2 + b * 0.8
out.write_to_file(sys.argv[3])

print("pyvips took {} milliseconds".format(1000 * (time.time() - start)))
```

pyvips is a "pipeline" image processing library, so that code will execute the load, processing and save all in parallel.

On this two core, four thread i5 laptop using Mark's two test images I see:

```
$ ./overlay-vips.py blobs.jpg ships.jpg x.jpg
took 39.156198501586914 milliseconds
```

So 39ms for two jpg loads, processing and one jpg save.

You can time just the blend part by copying the source images and the result to memory, like this:

```
a = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1]).copy_memory()
b = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[2]).copy_memory()

start = time.time()
out = (a * 0.2 + b * 0.8).copy_memory()
print("pyvips between memory buffers took {} milliseconds"
        .format(1000 * (time.time() - start)))
```

I see:

```
$ ./overlay-vips.py blobs.jpg ships.jpg x.jpg 
pyvips between memory buffers took 15.432596206665039 milliseconds
```

numpy is about 60ms on this same test.

I tried a slight variant of Mark's nice numba example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

import numba
from numba import jit, prange

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def method2(image1, image2, transparency):
   h, w, c = image1.shape
   for y in prange(h):
      for x in range(w):
         for z in range(c):
            image1[y][x][z] = image1[y][x][z] * transparency \
                    + (image2[y][x][z] * (1 - transparency))
   return image1

# run once to force a compile
i1 = np.array(Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert('RGB'))
i2 = np.array(Image.open(sys.argv[2]).convert('RGB'))
res = method2(i1, i2, 0.2)

# run again and time it
i1 = np.array(Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert('RGB'))
i2 = np.array(Image.open(sys.argv[2]).convert('RGB'))

start = time.time()
res = method2(i1, i2, 0.2)
print("numba took {} milliseconds".format(1000 * (time.time() - start)))

Image.fromarray(np.uint8(res)).save(sys.argv[3])
```

And I see:

```
$ ./overlay-numba.py blobs.jpg ships.jpg x.jpg 
numba took 8.110523223876953 milliseconds
```

So on this laptop, numba is about 2x faster than pyvips.

If you time load and save as well, it's quite a bit slower:

```
$ ./overlay-numba.py blobs.jpg ships.jpg x.jpg 
numba plus load and save took 272.8157043457031 milliseconds
```

But that seems unfair, since almost all that time is in PIL load and save.

Comment: If you do the timing in the same way for the Numba version, you will run into troubles. Since Numba is a compiler, it takes quite a while (in this example about 250-300ms) to compile the function. To avoid to measure this overhead, simply call the function once before timing. On a single threaded function you can also use `cache=True` to avoid recompilation when restarting the interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

My Raspberry Pi is unavailable at the moment - all I am saying is that there was some smoke involved and I do software, not hardware! As a result, I have only tested this on a Mac. It uses `Numba`.

First I used your Numpy code on these 2 images:

[image]

and

[image]

Then I implemented the same thing using `Numba`. The `Numba` version runs 5.5x faster on my iMac. As the Raspberry Pi has 4 cores, you could try experimenting with:

```
@jit(nopython=True,parallel=True)
def method2(image1,image2,transparency):
   ...
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

import numba
from numba import jit

def method1(image1,image2,transparency):
   result = image1*transparency+image2*(1-transparency)
   return result

@jit(nopython=True)
def method2(image1,image2,transparency):
   h, w, c = image1.shape
   for y in range(h):
      for x in range(w):
         for z in range(c):
            image1[y][x][z] = image1[y][x][z] * transparency + (image2[y][x][z]*(1-transparency))
   return image1

i1 = np.array(Image.open('image1.jpg').convert('RGB'))
i2 = np.array(Image.open('image2.jpg').convert('RGB'))

res = method1(i1,i2,0.4)
res = method2(i1,i2,0.4)

Image.fromarray(np.uint8(res)).save('result.png')
```

The result is:

[image]

Other thoughts... I did the composite in-place, overwriting the input `image1` to try and save cache space. That may help or hinder - please experiment. I may not have processed the pixels in the optimal order - please experiment.

Comment: You could also enable parallel mode to your Numba function. (@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True) , importing prange (`from numba import jit, prange` ) and changing the outer loop to `for y in prange(h):` This should also give quite a nice speedup

Comment: But still, isn't nuppy array summing faster? Because numpy provides "Fast mathematical operations over arrays"...

Comment: I don't know, I can't test it on my Raspberry Pi. The Numba version is 5x faster than Numpy on my Mac, so try it on your Raspberry Pi and see. Just start `ipython` and load the my code and you can time it with `%timeit res = method1(i1,i2,0.4)` and the same for method2.

Comment: Hi Mark, could you perhaps have those number accidentally reversed? Numpy is 5x faster than numba for me on my i5 laptop.

Comment: @jcupitt Hello John. I just checked them again on my iMac and the times were very consistent - I get 34.1ms for method1 and 6.28ms for method2. Not sure what to say and my Raspberry Pi is toast for the moment so I didn't bother trying to optimise anything much as the Raspberry Pi is a different beast altogether and optimisations would likely be different.

Comment: Huh how odd, on my i5 laptop I see 60ms for numpy and 450ms for numba. Perhaps my numba install is broken somehow?

Comment: @jcupitt I know very little about Numba - I have only used it on a couple of occasions as I have seen answers eulogising about its performance on StackOverflow. I have no idea how to debug it or probe its internal operations/versions/optimisations - the only testing I did is that it produces the same result.